# How to make valgrind displaying the memory status for daemon application?

Tags: c, valgrind

I have a C program which contains many memory allocation even from external libraries and I want to check periodically the total allocated memory by my application (library allocations included).

I tried with some linux commands like `ps euf`, `pmap $pid`, `cat /proc/$pid/status` but without any real results.

I make some research and I found the adequate tool todo that is with valgrind.

I tried to dump the memory when my application is running with:

```
valgrind --tool=drd --trace-alloc=yes
```

But I did not get result like the result displayed by valgrind at the end of execution.

How to make valgrind displaying the memory status (like the result displayed by valgrind at the end of execution) when my application is running?

Comment: valgrinds a powerful tool, he can do many things. if your under a Linux distrib, you can use **man valgrind** and **read** :). htop will   show you your total memory usage, virtually and physically.

Comment: How to make valgrind displaying the memory status periodically, and not at the end of execution because the application is a daemon.

Comment: You can also consult your platform's documentation to see if `malloc` offers any support. For example, on GCC you have `<malloc.h>` which gives you several diagnostic tools.

Comment: There is some flags that runs valgrind in parallel of your program, i don't know every flags, but i'm sure by browsing the man page you can find what you seek. -> http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [3.8.0 valgrind manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual), there is no such option for the core or for memcheck, and no mention on periodic or triggered behaviour in the signal section. `valgrind` can't do it out of the box.

While you might write a valgrind tool to do the job, you might re-think the approach and clarify what kind of memory usage you want, and if the system statistics might be sufficient for your task.

Comment: I see in the man page the option `valgrind --trace-alloc=yes` and it's helpful but with this option I get an error in the execution `valgrind: Bad option: --trace-alloc=yes`

Comment: @alk: No, it's simply a DRD-tool specific option, and he's running the default tool (memcheck).